# How to create msi with cx_freeze that will install font .ttf file

Tags: python, fonts, windows-installer, cx-freeze

I want to create an msi installation package with [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), that will install the application and also an included **ttf** font file on windows.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. On windows it shold be enough to copy the .ttf file to `C:\Windows\Fonts`.

So the `setup.py` for **cx_freeze** must have the data_files argument like :

```
setup(
    name='app',
    author='microo8',
    author_email='email@gmail.com',
    version = '0.1',
    description='',
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions, bdist_msi = bdist_msi_options),
    executables = executables,
    data_files = [('C:\\Windows\\Fonts', ['Ubuntu-L.ttf'])] #here is the desired font
)
```